# Find an example to explain that $f^{-1}(\mathcal{B}_{Y})\neq \mathcal{B}_{X}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

> I try to find an example to show that if a function $f: X\to Y$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(\mathcal{B}_{Y})\neq \mathcal{B}_{X}$,
>   where $f^{-1}(\mathcal{B}_{Y}):=\{f^{-1}(A): A\in \mathcal{B}_{Y}\}$.

Comment: Let $X$ be the set with two elements and the discrete topology with basis of singletons, let $Y$ be the set with two elementss and the indiscrete topology. Then  $id:X \to Y$ is automatically continuous, and is a counterexample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)=0$, where the topology is the usual topology. Then 
$$f^{-1}(\mathcal{B}_{Y})=\{ \emptyset, \mathbb R \} $$

Comment: Sorry, why $f(\emptyset)=0$?

Comment: In this way, how to understand the $\mathcal{B}_{Y}$? just only a point.

Comment: @LoveQYG No, $Y=\Bbb R$ so its Borel sets are the usual ones.

Comment: @LoveQYG If $A \subset \mathbb R$ is any Borel set then $f^{-1}(A)=\emptyset $ if $0 \notin A$ and $f^{-1}(A)=\mathbb R$ if $0\in A$.

Comment: @LoveQYG And for $f(\emptyset)=0$ you are confusing the image with the preimage... Note for example that $f^{-1}(\{2 \})=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ be the identity from the discrete space $X=\Bbb R$ to the usual topology endowed $Y=\Bbb R$. We cannot get every subset of $X$ as an inverse subset of a Borel subset of $Y$. Simply because the reals ($Y$) have non-Borel subsets.

Answer (score 0):

What about a constant function $f$? That would work, since then, for each $B=\mathcal B_Y$, $f^{-1}(B)$ is either $X$ or $\emptyset$.